# Latitude and Longitude of Zipcode?

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude

HI i am trying to retrieve Latitude and longitude of a given Zip code.

This is my code

```
 public ActionResult GoogleMap(string address, string Zip)
    {
        string Country = "US";
        int CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["CustomerID"]);
        string DefaultLocation = PrescriberModel.GetDefaultLocation((long)CustomerID).Address.ToString();
        ViewBag.PL = address;
        ViewBag.DF = DefaultLocation;

        string Lat = "";
        string Lon = "";
        string PostUrl = "http://ws.geonames.org/postalCodeSearch?postalcode=" + Zip + "&maxRows=10&country=" + Country;
       // WebRequest webRequest= null;
        WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
        if (webResponse == null)
        { }
        else
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
            string Result = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
            if (Result != "")
            {
                // Load the response into an XML doc
                XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                xdoc.LoadXml(Result);
                //  Navigate to latitude node
                XmlNodeList name = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("lat");
                if (name.Count > 0)
                {
                    Lat = name[0].InnerText;
                }
                //  Navigate to longitude node
                name = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("lng");
                if (name.Count > 0)
                {
                    Lon = name[0].InnerText;
                }
            }
        }

        ViewBag.Lat = Lat;
        ViewBag.Lng = Lon;
        return PartialView("_GoogleMap");
    }
```

I have picked up this code from [here](http://www.billsternberger.net/asp-net-mvc/latitude-and-longitude-lookup-with-jquery-c-asp-net-mvc/)

But this is throwing an error for me at **webRequest.GetResponse();**
I noticed that in that example WebRequest is not instantiated, more over WebRequest is a abstract Class, it cannot be instantiated.

Any help how i can make it Code work.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that i / we cant see how your `webRequest` instance is created.
This will work.

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://ws.geonames.org/postalCodeSearch?postalcode=" + Zip + "&maxRows=10&country=" + Country);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```